# Python3 get S3 file contents and consume them asynchronously

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, boto3

In Python3 I have a function collect() to get a lot of file contents from a S3 bucket, and another funtion to consume them asynchronously. But in the follow code the consume() start after collect() finished runnning, how to run consume() without waiting the end of collect()?

```py
await asyncio.gather(collect(s3_bucket_name, path_prefix, document_queue),
                         consume(document_queue, args.index_batch_size))

async def collect(s3_bucket_name: str, path_prefix: str, document_queue: asyncio.Queue):
    log.info("Start collecting")
    start_time = time.time()

    client = boto3.client("s3")
    paginator = client.get_paginator("list_objects_v2")
    operation_parameters = {"Bucket": s3_bucket_name, "Prefix": path_prefix}
    page_iterator = paginator.paginate(**operation_parameters)

    for page in page_iterator:
        index_documents.count += page["KeyCount"]
        contents = page.get("Contents", [])
        for obj in contents:
            key = obj.get("Key")
            response = client.get_object(Bucket=s3_bucket_name, Key=key)
            file_content = response["Body"].read().decode("utf-8")
            await document_queue.put(json.loads(file_content))

    end_time = time.time()
    log.info(f"Execution time of collect is {end_time - start_time} seconds")

async def consume(document_queue: asyncio.Queue, index_batch_size: int):
    log.info("Start consumming")
    start_time = time.time()

    while document_queue.qsize() > 0:
        objects_json = await document_queue.get()
        ...
```

Output:

Start collecting

Execution time of collect is xxx

Start consumming